# Problema con un while y/n que no termina de funcionar

Tags: java, while, try-catch, switch

soy nuevo en Java y estoy haciendo un programa para calculo de delays en subgraves, mi problema es que quería hacer un switch para que el usuario elija el tipo de arreglo y al finalizar continúe con unas sentencias de despedida, podría obviarlas, pero queda mejor resulto. Cuando introduces "y" para seguir en el programa no hay problema, pero al introducir "n" repite lo de "y", no soy capaz de hacer que salga del switch, ¿Alguien me puede ayudar?

```
int flag2=1;
while(flag2==1) {
    System.out.println("Selecciona 1 para arreglo en línea, 2 para cardioide y 3 para End Fire ");
                
    int flag4=0;
    while(flag4==0) {
        try {
            elec=sc.nextInt();
            flag4=1;
        } 
        catch(Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Introduce un número ");
            sc.nextLine();
        }
        finally {}
    }
            
    switch (elec) {
        case 1:
            sep=fren*2/3;
            System.out.printf("Separa tus subs a %.3fm siquieres tenerlos a 2/3 de lambda",sep );
            sepbis=fren*1/4;
            System.out.printf("\nSepara tus subs a %.3fm  si quieres tenerlos a 1/4 de lambda", sepbis);
            System.out.println("\n¿Quieres seguir en el programa? (y/n) ");
            String yn=sc.nextLine();
            if (yn.equals("y")) {
                flag2=0;
            }else {
                flag2=1;
            }
                    
            sc.nextLine();
            break;
```

Comment: Bienvenido/a a [es.so]: haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio. Primeramente... ¿Ya depuraste (`debug`) tu código? ¿Lo ejecutaste paso a paso? ¿Qué notas de extraño? Lee [ask].

Comment: Según veo, tienes la condición alrevés, no? Cuando `yn.equals("y")` haces `flag2=0`, y entonces el while primero termina, porque para continuar flag2 tiene que ser 1. Sospecho, entonces, que `yn.equals("y")` no está funcionando como quieres.

Answer (score 0):

El problema parece ser que `elec=sc.nextInt();` te coge el próximo número entero, pero te deja el salto de línea en el scanner, así que cuando luego haces `sc.nextLine()` te coge el salto de línea que queda, no la letra que pongas.

Para solucionarlo haz una llamada a `sc.nextLine()` después de `elec = sc.nextInt()`.

A parte, lo que te dije de que tienes el `if` al revés (a mi parecer).

El `try` te quedaría así:

```java
try {
    elec = sc.nextInt(); // Consume solo el numero.
    sc.nextLine(); // Consume el salto de linea que queda.
    flag4 = 1;
}
```